# Android RecyclerView notify doesn't works propetly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm making application with RecyclerView and sometimes I change items and notify instantly `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `notifyItemRemoved(position)`, but my app crashs sometimes but sometimes not with exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 55, found: 56
```

**Code #1:**
And my code:

```
imageList.add(file);
listener.onChange();
```

Listener:

```
@Override
public void onChange() {
   photoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

**Code #2:** 
And same with another part of code:

```
files.remove(file);
notifyItemRemoved(poss);
```

I don't know where is error. Do you have some idea what is possible error?
I can post some additional code if it is necessary.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Code from bug in code #2:

```
  for (File f : files) {
        if (f.getAbsolutePath().equals(file.getAbsolutePath())) {
            final int poss = files.indexOf(file);
            files.remove(file);
            notifyItemRemoved(poss);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is same, first part of code with adding crashes too

Comment: is your listener running on a separate thread?

Comment: I think problem is in your adapter

Comment: Can you show us the `Adapter`'s code?

Comment: Well there is lots of lines of code without any link with this problem, what part of code are you interested in?

Comment: I have added some part of code which I think it is possible relevant.

Comment: And do you remove the item from adapters collection?

Comment: What do you mean by remove the item from adapters collection